# How to serve an ember.js application through lighttpd?

Tags: ember.js, lighttpd

How can you serve an [ember.js](/questions/tagged/ember.js) published application with [lighttpd](/questions/tagged/lighttpd) while preserving the "deep link" functionality provided by ember and the [html5historyapi](/questions/tagged/html5historyapi) ? These are just the compiled static assets, generated by [ember-cli](/questions/tagged/ember-cli) with `ember build --environment production`. I've found that [lighttpd](/questions/tagged/lighttpd) can't properly serve such a site out of the box, as the deep linking won't work.

The problem is that [lighttpd](/questions/tagged/lighttpd) returns a 404 for ember's "virtual URLs" when such a page is first requested, presumably since they do not exist as directories or files on disk. These are URLs like `http://example.com/someresource/someid`, where only the physical file `http://example.com/index.html` and its related JavaScript files actually exists and should be used instead.

Apache has no problem with this: it will happily serve the `index.html` from the root, adds the rest of the URL as path arguments for the request, and JavaScript picks it up from there. But [lighttpd](/questions/tagged/lighttpd) doesn't see a `someresource` or `someid` file or directory, and serves a 404 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found to work is to use [lighttpd](/questions/tagged/lighttpd)'s [mod_rewrite](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite) to force the requests towards the main page, while excluding any static assets that are also part of the site which can be served directly.

This is a rewrite rule which maps everything which isn't a known asset on disk (`favicon.ico`, `assets/*`) to be served by `index.html`:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "^/(?!(?:assets/|favicon[.]ico))(.*)$" => "/index.html" )
```

Note that it doesn't pass on the query parameters, but JavaScript has the access to the original parameters if it needs to and the server doesn't have a need for query parameters when using Ember.

Of course if there are better solutions I'd like to hear about them, but I couldn't even find a discussion on the subject anywhere.